# 'node' is not recognized as an internal command or external, an executable program or a batch file

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, terminal, command

First of all, I wanted to learn Node.js, I opened my code editor then logged a simple word. but the problem is when I open my terminal I write :

```
node server.js
```

but it says :

```
'node' is not recognized as an internal command
```

or external, an executable program or a batch file.

I don't know how to fix the problem even in my editor's terminal.

Comment: Which operating system and terminal are you using? Have you installed node? If yes, where is it located?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you haven't installed node on your system. Be sure if you have installed node or not.

**Just open your terminal and type `node`**
If you don't see a message like this `Welcome to Node.js v14.12.0.` then check this [official download/setup link.](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)
If you're using Ubuntu, then follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64705440/node-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-command-or-external-an-executable-progr).
For any other Linux distro, just search `Install node on <manjaro>`.
*Change  with your distro name.*